# Dados recebidos de HTTPS vem encriptado?

Tags: php, segurança, criptografia, ssl, https

Se eu instalar certificado **SSL** e usar **HTTPS** em meu site, por exemplo, eu executo um formulário `POST`, os dados do formulário chegam encriptados ao servidor?

Se sim, como descriptografar usando PHP?.

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu? Você não consegue aceitar alguma?

Comment: Vinculado: [Quais são os benefícios de se usar https](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49561/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-benef%C3%ADcios-de-se-usar-https)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

O SSL/[TLS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) é uma camada de criptografia a nível de transporte. Isso significa que:

1. Sim, os dados chegam encriptados; somente o *browser* do usuário e o seu servidor têm acesso a eles, ninguém no meio do caminho pode vê-los ou alterá-los sem ser percebido;
2. Não é necessário fazer nada no PHP para descriptografar, pois o PHP opera na camada de aplicação, não de transporte. Como a imagem abaixo mostra, tudo o que está nas camadas acima dele (inclusive o próprio protocolo HTTP) continua operando normalmente, sem nem tomar conhecimento do que ocorre por baixo:

   [image: Diagrama mostrando o posicionamento do Tls em relação ao TCP e HTTP/FTP/SMTP]

   A *query string* e todo o corpo da requisição POST, embora estejam encriptados em trânsito, estarão disponíveis no seu formato original para o seu código PHP. De modo que para acessá-los, basta fazer da mesma forma que faria com uma conexão sem criptografia (i.e. um simples `http://`).

Comment: mais simples e ilustrativo seria difícil. Parabens

Answer (score 11):

A resposta do mgibsonbr já explica perfeitamente o que você deseja saber nesta pergunta. Como sei que você está interessado em criptografia *end-to-end* vou complementar algo importante para não usar a ferramenta errada.

Usar HTTPS não é fazer criptografia *end-to-end*. O conceito *end-to-end* só consegue ser aplicado de fato quando a criptografia é usada na camada da aplicação. Em tese seria possível aplicar em outras camadas, mas, dada a forma como elas funcionam na prática, não é possível sem fazer uma bela de uma gambiarra que não faz nenhum sentido. Pelo menos, não consigo ver de outra forma.

Usar HTTPS na forma como ele funciona hoje significa que haverá um intermediário, em algum momento haverá decrepitação da informação por um agente que não são os terminais. Como foi dito na outra resposta a aplicação não tem que lidar com a criptografia e em geral nem que o dados trafegaram criptografados, é totalmente transparente. Mesmo que o código PHP imediatamente criptografe de novo, a privacidade e garantia de autenticidade do dado já está comprometido - ainda que nada ruim seja feito com ele.

Independente de querer usar *end-to-end*, é bom que todos desenvolvedores saibam que o HTTPS só garante o transporte seguro dos dados. Quando o dado fica disponível para a aplicação, não há segurança alguma, um servidor comprometido ou uma aplicação que deixa brechas podem expor dados sem segurança alguma. E este é um entendimento errado muito comum. Há uma falsa impressão de segurança quando HTTPS é usado.

## Não existe meia segurança

Ou é seguro ou é inseguro. Ter insegurança por uma pequena fração de segundo é suficiente para classificarmos algo como inseguro. Qualquer brecha na aplicação ou comprometimento do servidor (mesmo por acesso autorizado) pode permitir acesso a uma informação que esteja rapidamente disponível sem criptografia.

E a criptografia que depende de chave precisa ter a chave provada de forma segura. Não adianta criptografar algo e disponibilizar as chaves no mesmo ambiente ou outro ambiente também comprometido. Se você consegue descriptografar, você precisar ter todas as chaves naquele ambiente.

Isto em geral não é considerado um problema. Há consciência que não há segurança total no servidor. Quando não está querendo alcançar E2E isto não é problema. Mas quando o objetivo é o E2E só as pontas podem estar vulneráveis. E é bom que se saiba que isto não tem solução. E2E só pode garantir que não haverá acesso durante todo processo de comunicação, quando chega na ponta já não dá para garantir mais nada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso ficou claro, porém voce me abriu uma brecha, veja de acordo com essa questao que eu tive essa duvida http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28828/como-o-https-ssl-funciona

Comment: e de acordo com o que ele explica o trafego é seguro, com HTTPS/SSL ele nao passa por mais pessoas além de Alice e Bob, agora o fato de o dado ficar desencriptado por 1 milesimo de segundo... Pode até quebrar a logica do end-to-end, mas o servidor ainda estará encriptando tudo (ok, quebrou a logica do end-to-end) mas a segurança continuou, me explique mais o motivo dos dados ficarem inseguros, por que ? e como alguem poderia estragar isso? ficou confusomas creio que entende minha duvida

Comment: Não existe meia segurança, ou está seguro ou não está. Quando você recebe a resposta HTTPS pelo PHP a segurança acaba ali. mesmo que você volte criptografar, mesmo que isto aconteça em uma fração de milésimo de segundo, se a sua aplicação tiver alguma brecha, se o seu servidor estiver comprometido (e ele pode estar comprometido por você mesmo, você pode estar dizendo que está tudo seguro mas pode estar espionando), é possível pegar os dados sem criptografia. Só o fato de chegar em um servidor que eu não tenho controle eu já sei que eu não posso confiar em privacidade alguma ali.

Comment: Eu sei que corro riscos da minha informação ser vazada independente da vontade do mantenedor do servidor (e ele pode ter vontade, ninguém me garante que não). Se você está inseguro por um ligeiro momento você está inseguro. Claro que alguém só poderá se apoderar de alguma informação se tiver acesso ao servidor. O problema é que é mais frequente do que deveria quem tem capacidade conseguir ter acesso à servidores indevidamente.

Comment: entendi perfeitamente o que disse e concordo plenamente (pelo fato de ter explicado bem) e ponte entre o usuario final e o inicial é quebrada ali, entendi. Se levarmos isso em consideração (devemos) nao existe segurança na internet.. ou existe alguma forma de arrumar este "quebra-mola" ?

Comment: De uma certa forma nada é seguro se não forem tomadas todas as precauções. A quantidade de servidores que estão rodando com invasores é uma enormidade. Parece coisa rara mas tem casos de servidores rodando anos assim e ninguém percebe.

Comment: e voce sabe me informar se existe alguma precauçao neste caso?

Comment: Tem mas é algo complexo de responder aqui. Envolve um estudo profundo no assunto segurança, coisa que não sou especialista. Quando você quer segurança precisa contratar quem tem competência comprovada. Mesmo assim não há garantias.

Comment: Confesso que fiquei um pouco confuso quando você falou que HTTPS não era *end-to-end*, somente após ler os comentários eu acho que eu entendi: se o site/aplicação estiver hospedado em um servidor **de terceiros**, estes têm acesso aos dados descriptografados. Certo? Mas digamos que uma empresa possui um servidor próprio, em suas próprias dependências, nesse caso pode-se considerar que a criptografia foi *end-to-end*, ou há algo mais que me escapa?

Comment: (Em tempo: se você não confia no seu provedor de hospedagem, nada do que você fizer vai garantir a segurança, pois como saber se esse servidor está de fato executando o seu código?)

Comment: É aí que a coisa fica um pouco confusa. Você leu isto? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49722/101. Até que ponto isto pode ser considerado *end-to-end*? Eu até dei um exemplo de uma situação que o servidor pode ser considerado um terminador na comunicação. Note que embora não esteja claro nesta pergunta, ele está interessado em algo com um outro contexto. Justamente no seu último comentário é que pega na segurança *end-to-end*. Este conceito determina que efetivamente só as partes que devam ter acesso a uma informação tenham este acesso. Isto só é possível se realmente não há intermediários...

Comment: com acesso à informação plana, o simples fato de você ter o servidor em um *datacenter* já não lhe dá esta garantia. Você pode confiar nele, mas nada garante que alguém acesse o servidor e se apodere de informações que estejam livres em algum momento. Nada garante que alguém com um mandato acesse o servidor. A única garantia é quando só as pontas mesmo tenham acesso. Claro que elas podem estar comprometidas também, podem ser obrigadas a usar sua chave e revelar a informação por mandato, mas não através de intermediário. @mgibsonbr

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, de fato eu havia entendido mal o que significava *end-to-end*...