# Quais são as camadas existentes em uma requisição HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: http, ssl, https

Eu dei uma atenção especial hoje pela manhã de ler algumas perguntas e respostas aqui no site que falam especificalmente sobre https/ssl.

Como por exemplo essas:

- [Dados recebidos de HTTPS vem encriptado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49842/dados-recebidos-de-https-vem-encriptado)
- [Quais são os benefícios de se usar HTTPS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49561/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-benef%C3%ADcios-de-se-usar-https?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Nessas duas, eu vi aparecendo mais de uma vez os termos *camada de transporte* e *camada da aplicação*.

Eu consegui entender alguma coisa, mas pensei que seria interessante fazer uma pergunta pra ver se poderia surgir mais detalhes.

Queria saber

- Além da *camada de transporte* e *camada da aplicação*, numa requisição http ou https, há alguma outra camada?
- O que diferencia essas camadas?
- O que ocorre exatamente na camada de transporte?
- Poderíamos dizer que um servidor com Apache e PHP seria a camada da aplicação?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Além da camada de transporte e camada da aplicação, numa requisição http ou https, há alguma outra camada?

Na verdade não é bem o HTTP ou HTTPS que tem camadas. É todo o tráfego que tem camadas. Isso é chamado de [modelo OSI (Open Systems Interconnection)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) criado por esta entidade que cuida dos padrões de interconexões. Ela está oficializada pela [ISO/IEC 7498-1](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=20269).

Cada camada tem uma função e uma maneira de ser formada. São elas (da mais alta para a mais baixa:

- [Application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) - Camada no *host*, cuida de [*dados*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_(computing)) no que é mais aparente para os humanos, alguns deles além do [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), são [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), e cada um opera como melhor lhe convier para atender a necessidade específica daquela aplicação.
- [Presentation layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_layer) - Camada no *host*, cuida de *dados* e faz o meio de campo entre a aplicação e a rede, em geral fazendo alguma conversão de dados, incluindo codificação de caractere, compressão e criptografia dos trechos de dados.
- [Session layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_layer) - Camada no *host*, cuida de *dados* e mantém um controle para que os diversos trechos de dados sejam considerados como um conjunto único de transmissão mantendo uma continuidade da comunicação. Não confundir com sessão da sua aplicação que não cuida da comunicação em si.
- [Transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) - Camada no *host*, cuida de [*segmentos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_segmentation) ou [*datagramas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram) que manipula a identificação do *host* e outras informações para garantir a transmissão adequada com outro *host*, fazendo a multiplexação, autenticação de dados para fornecer confiabilidade, etc.
- [Network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer) - Camada de mídia, cuida de [pacotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet) e trata da localização dos pontos (nós) que vão comunicar (rota, endereçamento, capacidade de tráfego). Em geral ocorre no hardware com apoio de *driver*.
- [Data link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer) - Camada de mídia, cuida de [*frames*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(networking)) de forma que ele seja entregue de um ponto a outro de forma confiável. Em geral só o hardware cuida disto. [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) é um dos mais usados. Exemplos são [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) e [IEEE_802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11).
- [Physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer) - Camada de mídia, cuida dos bits onde acontece a transmissão da forma mais bruta possível, o mais perto do meio material que mantém a corrente elétrica, ótica ou gerador de ondas. Cuida da voltagem, impedância, esse tipo de coisa.

> O que diferencia essas camadas?

Grosso modo, cada uma tem uma responsabilidade e elas vão se intercambiando para fornecer a melhor solução possível para uma determinada necessidade geral que não deixa de ser um monte de necessidades mais específicas.

Na maior parte do tempo o programador não precisa conhecer essas coisas em detalhes. Eventualmente precisa conhecer a camada de aplicação se quiser fazer algo mais avançado ou esteja construindo um aplicativo que fará uso das camadas de baixo, por exemplo está construindo um servidor web ou de e-mail.

Também há casos onde a comunicação precisa ser um nível mais baixo. Quem sabe você possa estar criando um novo protocolo para a camada de aplicação. Não é tão incomum se programar direto no TCP, por exemplo.

Abaixo disso já costuma cair mais em quem trabalha com telecomunicação.

Nem todas camadas são obrigatórias, principalmente as de cima. Obviamente que se as de baixo estão ausentes não usa o modelo OSI, o que desconheço algum uso.

> O que ocorre exatamente na camada de transporte?

Existem diversos protocolos usados nesta camada. Hoje o mais usado (depende do critério) é o [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), mas vários outros são usados também ([UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) por exemplo). Em geral o sistema operacional cuida de formá-lo, e as camadas superiores precisam pedir para ele ser montado e tratado adequadamente para depois delegar para quem cuida da camada inferior.

> Poderíamos dizer que um servidor com Apache e PHP seria a camada da aplicação?

O PHP certamente não tem nada com isso. O Apache é uma aplicação que gera tráfego e cuida da informação que vai na camada de aplicação, mas dizer que ele seria a própria camada seria errado. Ele monta o cabeçalho HTTP e o que podemos considerar [*payload*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188469/101). É irônico que o Hyper Text **Transport** Protocol seja a camada de aplicação.

Note abaixo que existem diversos cabeçalhos que vão sendo adicionados em cada camada e esse "Dados", que é o [*payload*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188469/101).

[image: Camadas OSI]

Não vou entrar em detalhes para a pergunta não ser ampla, mas dúvidas específicas cabem, embora algumas talvez comecem entrar em outro escopo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se o protocolo HTTP é um protocolo de aplicação, portanto da camada de aplicação, e se o Apache Server é um servidor HTTP, portanto interpretando requisições HTTP, por que o Apache não é a camada de aplicação? Neste caso onde temos um servidor HTTP, quem é a camada de aplicação?

Comment: Se chamar o Apache de camada de aplicação terá que chamar o compilador de linguagem de programação. Um é um agente que lida com o outro.

Comment: Minha dúvida permanece: Neste caso onde temos um servidor HTTP, quem é a camada de aplicação? No meu entendimento, o Apache recebe bytes por uma conexão websocket, interpreta esses bytes como texto, e interpreta este texto segundo o protocolo HTTP (verbo, uri, parâmetros...). Se é o Apache é o componente responsável por interpretar os dados recebidos obedecendo o protocolo HTTP, por que ele não é a camada de aplicação, e neste caso qual é o componente que representa a aplicação?

Comment: Achei que a analogia seria suficiente. A camada de aplicação é a camada de aplicação, ela não precisa ser outra coisa. Ela tem agentes que a manipulam. Um compilador faz essencialmente a mesma coisa que você disse, cada um com sua função, e ele não é chamado de linguagem de programação, a não ser por um leigo. Um moedor de carne é a carne. Um aplicativo não é uma camada de aplicação, ele é apenas um aplicativo. Você pode clicar nos *links* e ver na Wikipedia se consegue entender. Lá não faz essa confusão também.

Comment: Naturalmente a camada em si é um conceito, e um componente de hardware ou software implementa as funções da camada, representando-a (não faz muito sentido "manipular" uma camada). Em uma comunicação HTTP, o Apache implementa a função da camada de aplicação.