# O que é payload?

Tags: json, terminologia, http

Sempre tenho visto em alguns *frameworks* que trabalham com REST ou com envio de dados em formato  JSON numa requisição o uso da expressão *payload*.

- O que significa esse nome em requisições HTTP?
- O que é especificamente um *payload*? É um corpo de uma requisição em formato JSON?

Um exemplo do termo sendo usado pelo Google Chrome:

Exemplo 1:

<kbd>[image: Imagem do Google Chrome indicando o nome Payload]</kbd>

Exemplo 2:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Payload em termos de hacking é um script que é injetado em um sistema através de alguma falha e depois é executado como uma espécie de administração remota. Só que acho que o termo que você procura é em outro contexto.

Comment: O nome formal e mais utilizado no contexto HTTP não é payload mas sim ***"body"***, em português *"corpo"*. "Payload" por sua vez é bastante utilizado em message queueing.

Comment: @Caffé não sei se é bem isso não, hein. Veja essa pergunta no [SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118249/whats-the-difference-between-request-payload-vs-form-data-as-seen-in-chrome)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Esta resposta no SOEN linka a RFC ainda não aprovada. A especificação corrente é esta: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html.  A nova RFC chama "tudo" de payload, dividindo entre "payload header fieds" e "payload **body**"; o que é bacana porque os campos do cabeçalho também podem conter informação relevante de aplicação e não apenas dados de transporte.

Comment: Sobre a segunda pergunta: sim, em HTTP o payload body **pode ser** um JSON, o que é bastante comum nas APIs REST atualmente. Mas também pode ser um XML, um dicionário chave-valor dos campos de um formulário HTML, o próprio HTML de uma página, ou qualquer outra coisa. Veja que o "payload header fields", por sua vez, embora também chamado de "payload"  na futura RFC, não pode conter JSON, ou não deveria sob pena de causar uma bela bagunça no header e fugir do padrão e da proposta do header.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Seria o dado que realmente interessa sem metadados, sem o cabeçalho de transmissão ou outras informações acessórias usadas apenas como infraestrutura para transmitir o que importa. Então ele é o corpo da informação, é o que é útil de tudo o que está sendo transmitido.

A tradução literal "carga que paga" poderia ser chamada de "conteúdo que vale a pena".

O significado pode ser diferente em outros contextos, mesmo da computação.

Exemplo de pacote TCP (não achei um bom de HTTP, mas a ideia é parecida). O Data (verdinho) é o *payload*:

[image: Pacote TCP]

Em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186437/101) tem um diagrama mostrando as várias camadas de comunicação e todas possuem cabeçalhos que vão sendo adicionados em cada camada e a parte de "dados", que é o tal do *payload*. Se o *payload* for muito pequeno o [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) dos cabeçalhos de todas camadas se torna um fardo. Você pode ter algum controle sobre o tamanho do *payload* em camada alta, mas nas mais baixas o controle vai ficando menor, *payloads* muito grandes tendem ser fatiados antes de serem transmitidos.

O *payload* não tem formato de texto ou binário. O fato de ser JSON é apenas circunstancial. Em HTTP ele até é um texto por imposição do protocolo, mas pode ser o HTML, CSS, JS, texto bruto, binário codificado em [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), etc.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Exemplo de mensagem HTTP: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/images/HTTP_RequestMessageExample.png (sem mais observações à resposta pra não te chatear hehehe).

Answer (score 25):

Em termos gerais, o ***payload*** ("carga", em português) é o conteúdo enviado por um meio de transporte, ou ***carrier***. Alguns exemplos:

- O conteúdo `HTML` é o *payload* enviado via protocolo `HTTP`;
- O conteúdo `JSON` é o *payload* enviado via protocolo `HTTP` a partir do *endpoint* `REST`*;
- O conteúdo `XML` é o *payload* enviado via protocolo `HTTP` a partir do *endpoint* `SOAP`*.

Em algumas terminologias o *carrier* é também chamado de *envelope*.

*<sub>Apenas para fins de exemplo. Endpoints REST e SOAP podem gerar *payloads* em outros formatos.</sub>

Comment: Sob o ponto de vista do HTTP, o HTML (ou qualquer outra sequência de bytes transportada) seria o payload. Entretanto, sob o ponto de vista da aplicação como um todo, a estrutura do HTML, do JSON e do XML seriam carriers, enquanto que a carga transportada seriam os dados que estão representados e estruturados neste HTML, JSON ou XML.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, exatamente - é uma questão do ponto de vista da camada consumidora.

Answer (score 3):

Payload em termos de protocolo é nada mais nada menos que seu conteúdo. Por exemplo o Payload de um protocolo IP pode ser o TCP. Ou seja, a grosso modo é aquilo que representa o dado a ser transportado pelo protocolo. Acontece o mesmo com o HTTP e o Json. E o payload apresentado dentro deste contexto é o que vai ser transportado no Json da request.

Answer (score -3):

Payload no contexto da tua pergunta é exatamente como OnoSendai respondeu, o que significa todo o JSON mostrado do teu exemplo.
Sempre vai do contexto da pergunta. Eu costumo entender como payload a carga extra que precisa ser trafegada quando existe um controle de autenticação e autorização por token, como por exemplo em JWT, neste caso além do registro trafegado você precisa trafegar o token e a cópia fiel do dado depois novamente para fazer um POST por exemplo, sendo assim uma "carga extra", payload, para trafegar a carga você é obrigado a trafegar também o token e sua dependência, pagar uma carga, por isso também é chamado PAYLOAD. Confuso? Mas no final das contas no teu contexto o payload é tudo o que vem no JSON mostrado, os dados e o token se houver.

Comment: Você definiu muito bem o que não é um payload.