# Guardar Imagem Vinda de Upload em uma variável PHP

Tags: php

Como capturar uma imagem que vem de um input do tipo file do HTML, em uma variável PHP? Por exemplo com um input de texto funciona desta forma:

```
$vnome = ($_POST["f_nome"]);
echo $vnome;
```

```html
<input type="text" name="f_nome">
```

Como fazer o mesmo com uma imagem? 
É possível guardar imagem em uma variável PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O servidor junto com o PHP antes de executar o teu script já fez o "parse" do [***PAYLOAD***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188469/3635) e salvou a imagem na pasta `./tmp` configurada pelo php.ini em [`upload_tmp_dir`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir), então você pode fazer o upload normalmente e usar `file_get_contents`, um exemplo básico seria:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="arquivo" multiple>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

E o php seria:

```
<?php

if (empty($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])) {
     die('Erro no upload');
}

//Pega os dados do upload
$dados_da_imagem = file_get_contents($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);
```

Se quiser exibir na tela terá que usar [***data URI scheme***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), algo como:

```
$dados_da_imagem = file_get_contents($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);

echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,', base64_encode($dados_da_imagem),'">';
```

---

Agora se a sua intenção é exibir um preview da imagem antes de completar o upload, recomendo que faça isso no ***front-end***, antes mesmo de enviar o POST, exemplo de ferramentas JavaScript:

- http://www.dropzonejs.com/#
- http://opoloo.github.io/jquery_upload_preview/ (pra quem usa jQuery)

Comment: Dessa forma é possível chamar o "$dados_do_upload" para aparecer a imagem?

Comment: @HenriqueBretone sim, é possivel, você não viu o exemplo `echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,', base64_encode($dados_da_imagem),'">';`?

Comment: @HenriqueBretone Agora se a sua intenção é exibir um preview da imagem **antes de completar o upload** (tipo o usuário quer checar se é a foto correta), recomendo que faça isso no front-end, antes mesmo de enviar o POST, exemplo de ferramentas JavaScript: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ ou http://opoloo.github.io/jquery_upload_preview/

Comment: Não a intenção não era fazer uma thumbnail de preview, a ideia era pegar a imagem no PHP e jogar ela em um modelo HTML para gerar um PDF que aparece-se a imagem, estou fazendo isso com textos tranquilamente o problema é a necessidade de mostrar a imagem que o usuário fez o upload no arquivo PDF.