# O que é TCP e UDP? Qual a diferença entre os dois protocolos?

Tags: terminologia, redes

Sempre que me deparo com algum medidor de velocidade, ou até mesmo quando se fala em transmissão de serviços como Streaming, esses dois termos são citados de alguma forma, mas o que eles significam afinal? Qual a diferença entre os dois?

Comment: Alguma informação extra sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101. Também relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186437/101

Comment: Questões deste tipo podem ser feitas em inglês no https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 24, accepted):

O TCP e o UDP são protocolos parte de um modelo conceitual(OSI model) que padroniza as funções de comunicação na computação divididas em 7 camadas.

[image: http://slideplayer.com.br/slide/355743/2/images/13/Modelo+OSI+-+Processo+de+encapsulamento.jpg]

TCP e UDP estão na camada de transporte que é responsável pela transferência eficiente, confiável e econômica dos dados entre a máquina de origem e a máquina de destino, independente do tipo, topologia ou configuração das redes físicas existentes entre elas, garantindo ainda que os dados cheguem sem erros e na seqüência correta.

**[UDP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Vantagens_do_uso_do_UDP)**

> O UDP é uma escolha adequada para fluxos de dados em tempo real, especialmente aqueles que admitem perda ou corrompimento de parte de seu conteúdo, tais como vídeos ou voz (VoIP). ...

**[TCP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)**

> ...é sobre o qual que se assentam a maioria das aplicações cibernéticas, como o SSH, FTP, HTTP — portanto, a World Wide Web. O Protocolo de controle de transmissão provê **confiabilidade**...

A diferença entre eles pode ser vista nos headers:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `TCP` preza pela confiabilidade agregando em seu `header` bits de controle de fluxo e recebimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já o `UDP` dispensa esses bits de controle.

Pode se dizer que o `TCP` é orientado a conexão através do seu [Acknowledgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acknowledgement_(data_networks)) e o `UDP` não, uma vez que não é criada uma conexão, há apenas o envio direto de dados.

Answer (score 17):

Em linhas bem gerais - o protocolo **TCP** divide a informação a ser transmitida em pacotes. Esses pacotes são enviados ao destino e, caso algum deles não chegue, ou chegue corrompido, o destino pode solicitar por esses pacotes de novo. Graças ao cabeçalho que o protocolo define em cima de cada pacote, o cliente consegue determinar se algum deles está faltando ou não.

Já o protocolo **UDP** também quebra a informação em pacotes menores mas não tem o cuidado com a integridade ou a correção de perdas. Os dados são enviados e não há como o cliente saber se algum foi perdido ou se foi corrompido. Isso acontece pois no UDP, não há um cabeçalho tão elaborado quanto o do TCP.

Em termos práticos, o protocolo TCP é mais robusto e mais pesado. Deve ser usado em situações que você quer garantir a integridade ou a ordem absoluta da informação transmitida, como por exemplo, ao fazer o download de um arquivo.

Já o UDP é mais leve, porém essa leveza vem do fato que ele tolera perdas de pacotes. Deve ser usado em situações onde isso não seja um grande problema, como jogos online, streaming de vídeo e de voz.

Comment: Esse detalhe fica mais nítido quando tratado da conexão. O TCP funciona sobre uma conexão entre os dois terminais, sendo que o transmissor apenas envia os pacotes quando a conexão é estabelecida, garantindo que o receptor esteja preparado para recebê-los. Já o UDP envia os pacotes "sem dó"; se o receptor receber, melhor, se não, problema dele.