# Quais as vantagens de usar um "generator" (yield) no PHP?

Tags: php, yield, generators

A partir do PHP 5.5 foi implementado na linguagem o *generator*. Ele pode ser utilizado dentro de uma função a partir da palavra chave `yield`.

No [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.generators.overview.php), temos um exemplo onde um é comparado a função `range(0, 1000000)` (que teoricamente gastaria 100MB de memória) e uma implementação de `xrange` através dos *generators* (que reduziria o consumo da memória para 1 kilobyte).

Exemplo do manual:

```
<?php
function xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {
    if ($start < $limit) {
        if ($step <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be +ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    } else {
        if ($step >= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be -ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Note that both range() and xrange() result in the same
 * output below.
 */

echo 'Single digit odd numbers from range():  ';
foreach (range(1, 9, 2) as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
echo "\n";

echo 'Single digit odd numbers from xrange(): ';
foreach (xrange(1, 9, 2) as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
?>
```

Além da vantagem de economizar essa memória e simplificar o uso de um *iterator*, quais são as outras vantagens de utilizar o *generator* no PHP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No fundo, geradores não são para economizar memória. Isto é mais um efeito colateral bem-vindo. Eles existem para criar sequências de dados sob demanda.

A ideia geral dele é poder controlar melhor o que acontece entre a geração de cada elemento da sequência.

Uma das vantagens é produzir código com melhores abstrações. Você encapsula o mecanismo de como se obtém o dado dentro de uma função e deixa outra função, provavelmente em um *loop*, manipular estes dados sem se preocupar em como ele foi obtido. Você separa o mecanismo da regra de negócio.

Ele também permite o que se chama [*lazy evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) em que você só exerce a computação de um item da sequência quando e se realmente você vai usá-lo. Sem o gerador é muito comum gerar sequências de dados enormes, provavelmente em listas ou *arrays*, e gastar um tempo enorme para gerar todos os elementos e depois só usar de fato alguns deles e descartar o resto. O gerador economiza memória e processamento.

Uma outra utilização é na criação de [máquina de estados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) e [corrotinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) já que ele consegue manter estado entre as chamadas de suas execuções. Ele tem pausas naturais.

O funcionamento de um gerador é mais ou menos igual em todas as linguagens que o possuem. Eu já [respondi algo sobre isto em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101) que tem um gerador bem sofisticado. Lá tem alguns bons exemplos.

O ganho em memória é relativo. Se você precisar de toda a sequência gerada e usada ao mesmo tempo, não há ganho (se souber o que está fazendo).

Geradores não são ótimos para todos os casos. Eles provocam em pouco de *overhead*. Não que isto seja motivo para não usar, mas se não fornecer uma real vantagem não tem porque aceitar um *overhead*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você é o cara :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Você não entendeu da outra vez que eu te falei da pressa de aceitar uma resposta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/494/101 :)

Comment: Não me lembro da "outra vez". Mas estou lendo aqui :)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49561/quais-s%c3%a3o-os-benef%c3%adcios-de-se-usar-https/49580#comment100347_49561

Comment: Ah, sim. Me lembrei. Isso é verdade, acaba não dando oportunidade para pessoas que estão com o texto aberto no navegador clique em "adicionar uma resposta"

Comment: Até pode mas desincentiva, as pessoas querem ter a oportunidade da sua resposta ser aceita, quando você aceita logo quando alguém posta uma resposta, dificilmente você terá uma segunda, que potencialmente pode até lhe ajudar mais do que a primeira. Claro que você pode trocar, mas a maioria não troca, então quem responde sabe que é quase certo que ele não terá a aceitação e pode nem responder por causa disto. Também porque você já está satisfeito, não tem porque colocar mais alguma coisa.

Comment: Vou atender às dicas para prosseguir como um bom usuário da comunidade :)

Comment: Li a resposta e os comentários e fiquei com uma dúvida, que se acumulou de algo que li antes sobre o yield. Ele é similar ao "return" ou faz a mesma coisa?

Comment: Não, este é um engano típico. Ele provoca um `return`, mas ele é um mecanismo que guarda um estado para poder continuar de onde parou. A parte do `yield` em si é só esta, mas ela sempre funciona em conjunto com o `return`, por isso é comum ter só um comando que faça as duas coisas "simultaneamente". Se nenhum das respostas ajudou entender totalmente, tente fazer uma perguntas ainda mais específica.

Comment: entendi mais ou menos, vou fazer uma pergunta para saber a diferença entre o yield e o return, acho que talvez possa me ajudar melhor :)