# Como declarar uma função anônima no Python?

Tags: python, funções, função-anônima

Como faço para declarar e como funciona uma função anônima do `Python`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode criar funções anônimas em Python através de uma expressão [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

Segundo a documentação:

> As expressões lambda têm a mesma posição sintática como expressões. Eles são um atalho para criar funções anônimas; a expressão `lambda  argumentos: expressão` produz um objeto de função. O objeto não identificado se comporta como um objeto com função definida.

Exemplo:

```
def foo(x):
   return x*x
```

Poderia ser feita assim:

```
foo = lambda x: x*x
print(foo(10))
# 100
```

Uma função com `lambda` não tem limites em relação ao número de argumentos (incluindo argumentos opcionais), ela não pode conter mais do que uma expressão, em certas situações em que você precise criar algo mais complexo de preferência em usar uma função normal ao invés de um `lambda`.

Sobre seu uso isso é uma questão de estilo, usa-los não é necessário, mas pode usar em qualquer lugar, por exemplo para encapsular um código especifico, em funções normais que tenham somente uma linha.

Comment: Tem como fazer em últiplas linhas essa expressão `lambda`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters São *one-lines*. Essa [pergunta](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99243/why-doesnt-python-allow-multi-line-lambdas) cita alguns motivos para isso.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Até tem como fazer, mas foge um pouco do estilo "*Pythônico*" dê uma olhada [aqui](http://billmill.org/multi_line_lambdas.html).

Comment: Não, vamos seguir o padrão. Já vi gambiarras de mais no PHP :(

Answer (score 9):

## Uso com múltiplas linhas

O uso básico a resposta do QMechanic já deu. Python não tem uma forma geral de uso de funções anônimas. *Lambda* é uma forma específica de função anônima que não costuma ser usada com códigos de mais de uma linha. Em programação usando estilo funcional é muito comum as expressões terem apenas uma linha. A sintaxe pensa em concisão de código. Se ele não pode ser conciso provavelmente tem algo errado. Como se costuma dizer: "não é do jeito pitônico".

Se isto realmente for necessário a solução é delegar a execução para uma função normal.

Para declarar uma função anônima como *lambda*:

```
funcao = lambda x: filtro(x, lambda y: y > 0, lambda z: print(z))
```

A função que realmente executa a ação:

```
def filtro(lista, predicado, acao):
    for item in lista:
        if predicado:
            acao(item)
```

Para usar:

```
funcao([10, -20, 30])
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Yay9og). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/OneLineLambda). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/OneLineLambda.py).

Resolvi o problema das múltiplas linhas e ainda usei *lambdas* de várias formas.

## Uso geral

Sempre que você precise delegar processamento para um outro ponto da aplicação ela é útil. Ela costuma ser usada para fornecer [*lazy evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). Em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50208/101) você aprendeu usar isto (em PHP) com `yield`. Com *lambdas* você deixa o processamento básico a cargo de uma função mais concreta que recebe a injeção de uma ação específica que personalizará esta função. Então é uma forma de conseguir uma melhor **abstração** através de delegação.

De uma maneira geral é uma forma de passar algoritmos como se fossem dados. Evidentemente que isto é otimizado e não passa o código fonte, em geral é passado apenas uma referência para o código existente em outro lugar da memória.

Em algumas linguagens o seu uso é visto como algo positivo, em outras não, em Python há opiniões para todo lado.

É óbvio que ela não é necessária para nada a não ser facilitar o trabalho do programador.

## Terminologia

Embora cada linguagem use o termo de um jeito ligeiramente diferente algumas usam outros termos para a mesma coisa, *lambda* costuma ser uma função anônima muito simples que implicitamente retorna um valor (não precisa usar um `return`) e pode capturar variável de escopo léxico como uma *closure*.

Termos comumente usados que podem significar a mesma coisa ou indica pequenas diferentes entre os conceitos: *function pointer*, *functor*, *anonymous function*, *fisrt class function*, *function object*, *high order function*, *nested function* (este acho um pouco enganador), *callback* (que também é possível sem ser exatamente uma *lambda*), *inline function* (acho este termo mais ambíguo ainda).

## Implementação

A implementação exata deste mecanismo varia de linguagem para linguagem. Não sei exatamente como foi implementado no Python mas o mais comum é que seja criado um objeto que possui uma função normal mais uma estrutura para armazenar variáveis capturadas quando a *lambda* se comporta como uma clausura. Normalmente este objeto possui uma infraestrutura extra que permite manipular a função de formas diversas. Até onde eu sei em Python isto é fornecido para qualquer função, até porque todas elas possuem capacidade de uso de *closures*, não só *lambdas*. Por isto em Python é dito que *lambda* é apenas um açúcar sintático. Você pode armazenar funções normais como dados.

Este objeto armazena as variáveis capturadas temporariamente até não ter mais necessidade. O *garbage collector* pode resolver isto embora seja fácil vazar o recurso se ele não puder determinar o tempo de vida com precisão. Depende da qualidade do GC na implementação específica.

## Funções de alta ordem

Só para citar uma das formas de obter o mesmo resultado sem usar *syntax sugar*:

```
def linear(a, b):
    def result(x):
        return a * x + b
    return result

conta = linear(1, 2) //conta será uma função que armazenam estes dois argumentos enclausurados
conta(3) //executa a função result onde a e b valem 1 e 2 respectivamente com argumento 3 p/ x
```

Comment: O cara escreveu uma livro para mim, cara! Valeu