# Implementando um traceroute TCP

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando entender o código abaixo (achei na internet):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from scapy.all import *

target = input("Informe um alvo: ")
destport = input("Porta de destino: ")

port = int(destport)

ans,unans=sr(IP(dst=target,ttl=(1,30))/TCP(dport=port,flags="S"))
ans.summary(lambda s,r: r.sprintf("%IP.src%\t{ICMP:%ICMP.type%}\t{TCP:%TCP.flags%}"))
```

Eu não consigo entender de maneira alguma a última linha:

```
ans.summary(lambda s,r: r.sprintf("%IP.src%\t{ICMP:%ICMP.type%}\t{TCP:%TCP.flags%}"))
```

Alguém poderia, por favor, me explicar detalhadamente a última linha do programa? Por que usar `sprintf` em vez de `print`? Achei super confuso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ans, unans = sr(IP(dst=target, ttl=(1, 30)) / TCP(dport = port, flags = "S"))
```

De acordo com a documentação, a função [`sr`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr) é usada para o envio de pacotes, o resultado é uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) com os pacotes e respostas e pacotes sem resposta, e são atribuídos as variáveis `ans` e `unans` respectivamente.

`dst` é usado para definir o destino os pacotes, [`ttl`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_Live) define o tempo de vida do pacote, cada sistema operacional tem um padrão diferente, por exemplo, no Linux pode ser *64*, no Windows é *128*. No código o `ttl` vai ser entre *1* até *30*. Por fim, é definido a porta e *flag* indicando `SYN`.

```
ans.summary(lambda s,r: r.sprintf("%IP.src%\t{ICMP:%ICMP.type%}\t{TCP:%TCP.flags%}"))
```

A variável `ans` contém os pacotes e respostas resultantes da função `sr`, o método `summary` é para mostrar um resumo de cada pacote, [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) é uma palavra chave do Python que indica uma função anônima de uma linha somente, `s` e `r` são os argumentos dessa função ([**nessa pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50422/6454) existem mais informações sobre o assunto). Uma outra forma de fazer isso seria assim:

```
for s, r in ans:
  print ("{} \t {} \t {}".format(r.scr, r[ICMP].type, r[TCP].flags))
```

**Nota**: Não testei o código acima!

`sprintf` é uma função própria do Scapy com o objetivo de formatar a *string* com os valores dos campos do pacote, o formato pode incluir diretivas que começam e terminam com `%`, por exemplo: `IP.src`, `ICMP.type`, `TCP.flags`. [**Neste link**](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/blob/master/scapy/packet.py#L879) você pode ver a implementação.

Para mais informações [**veja a documentação**](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#starting-scapy).

Comment: obrigado. O sistema só deixa eu liberar a reconpensa em 6 horas... Assim que disponível, eu te passo!