# Criando um ARPING

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#Fazer arping de conexao

import sys
from datetime import datetime
from scapy.all import *

try:
    interface = input ("\n[*] Set interface: ")
    ips = input("[*] Set IP RANGE or Network: ")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n user aborted")
    sys.exit()

print("Scanning...")
start_time = datetime.now()

conf.verb = 0

ans,unans = srp(Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = ips), timeout = 2, iface = interface ,inter= 0.1)

print("\n\tMAC\t\tIP\n")

for snd,rcv in ans:
    print(rcv.sprintf("%Ether.src% - %ARP.psrc%"))

stop_time = datetime.now()
total_time = stop_time - start_time
print("\n[*] Scan Completed")
print("[*] Scan Duration: %s" %(total_time))
```

Este código foi pego na internet para estudos.
Não consegui entender duas linhas:

```
ans,unans = srp(Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = ips), timeout = 2, iface = interface ,inter= 0.1)
```

e

```
 print(rcv.sprintf("%Ether.src% - %ARP.psrc%"))
```

O que significa ,`inter= 0.1` e `rcv.sprintf` ? 
O que é `conf.verb = 0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = ips), timeout = 2, 
iface = interface, inter= 0.1)
```

A função [`srp`](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/blob/037352ed68dfed4547199c52d9ec126fd0e2640a/scapy/sendrecv.py#L353) tem o mesmo propósito que `sr` (explicado [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146626/6454)), a diferença é que `srp` envia e recebe os pacotes na [camada *2*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camada_de_enlace_de_dados), e `sr` na [camada *3*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camada_de_rede). Nesse código você está usando o [Ethernet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet).

Segundo a documentação, o parâmetro `inter` é usado para especificar o tempo em segundos de espera entre cada pacote enviado. `conf.verb` é para ativar ou desativar o *[verbose mode](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/v/verbose-mode.htm)*, por padrão é *1* (ativado), para desativar, o valor é *0*.

O `sprintf` como explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146626/6454), faz a formatação customizada dos resultados. É algo semelhante a isto:

```
class Formatacao:        
    def sprintf(self, formato):
        while "%" in formato:
            final = formato.rindex("%")
            inicio  = formato[final:].index("%")

            formato = formato[:final] + formato[final + inicio + 1:]
            palavras = formato.split()

        for palavra in palavras:
            if hasattr(self, palavra):
                valor = getattr(self, palavra)

                formato = formato.replace(palavra, str(valor))

        return formato

class Pessoa(Formatacao):
    def __init__(self, nome, sexo, peso, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.sexo = sexo
        self.peso = peso
        self.idade = idade
```

No *Scapy*, esse processo de formatação é bem mais complexo, com mais variáveis e verificações, no código acima se você passar uma palavra entre `%`, o método [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) vai verificar se a *palavra* é um nome de algum objeto da classe `Pessoa`, se for, pegamos seu valor com a função [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) e substituímos a *palavra* pelo valor com a função [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```
pessoa = Pessoa("Joao", "M", 70, 21)
print (pessoa.sprintf("%nome% tem %idade% anos"))
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/ucMTVf)

Você pode ver o código da função `sprintf` do *Scapy* [**aqui**](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/blob/17a550a8e832c4f8976d6cd961f79e2ab2a9317b/scapy/packet.py#L879).

Sempre que tiver alguma dúvida olhe também a [**documentação**](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#starting-scapy)!