# Como "simular" um Generator em versões anteriores ao PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, yield, generators

A partir do PHP 5.5 podemos utilizar `yield` ao invés do `return` nas funções e, com isso, criamos `Generators`.

As razões para a utilização do `yield` pode ser vista aqui [Quais as vantagens de usar um Generator (yield) no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50208/quais-as-vantagens-de-usar-um-generator-yield-no-php)

Porém me surgiu uma questão: Como poderia fazer pra implementar algo parecido com um `Generator` em versões anteriores ao PHP 5.5?

Gostaria de um exemplo onde eu poderia substituir a função `range`, por conta da economia de memória.

Exemplo PHP 5.5:

```
function xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {

    for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i += $step) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### O que é uma função generator?

A função generator é efetivamente uma forma mais compacta e eficiente para escrever um Iterator. Ele permite que você defina uma função (seu xrange), para calcular e retornar valores enquanto você está em loop:

```
foreach (xrange(1, 10) as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value", PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Saída:**

```
0  =>  1 
1  =>  2 
... 
9  =>  10
```

### Já que não há suporte para versões antigas, posso faze-lo com funções "normais"??

Agora você pode se perguntar por que não simplesmente usar ["Velho e bom nativo range "](http://php.net/range) para alcançar essa saída. E você está certo. A saída seria a mesma. **A diferença é como chegamos lá**.

Quando usamos `range`, isso irá executar toda a matriz de números na memória e retornar toda a matriz para o `foreach` que irá, em seguida, fornecer os valores. Em outras palavras, o `foreach` operará na própria matriz. O `range` e o foreach irão apenas "conversar" uma vez. Pense nisso como a obtenção de um pacote nos correios. O entregador irá entregar-lhe o pacote e ir embora. E então você desembrulha o pacote inteiro, tirando tudo o que está lá dentro.

### Exemplos:

```
<?php
// array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}

// The step parameter
// array(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
foreach (range(0, 100, 10) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}

// Usage of character sequences
// array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i');
foreach (range('a', 'i') as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
// array('c', 'b', 'a');
foreach (range('c', 'a') as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
?>
```

Comment: Essa resposta parece não responder a pergunta, não vejo nela nenhuma forma de simular um Generator, apenas uma explicação sobre o que é um.

Answer (score 1):

Para simular um `Generator` em versões anteriores ao `PHP 5.5`, seria necessário criar uma classe que implemente `Iterator`.

Veja de maneira simples como funcionaria:

```
class XRange implements Iterator
{
    protected $value = 0;

    protected $limit;

    protected $step;

    protected $initial;

    protected $key = 0;

    public function __construct($value, $limit, $step = 1)
    {
        $this->value = $this->initial = $value;

        $this->limit = $limit;

        $this->step = $step;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->value = $this->initial;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        $this->value += $this->step;

        ++$this->key;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return $this->value <= $this->limit;
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }
}
```

E nós podemos utilizá-la simplesmente assim:

```
foreach(new XRange(1, 10, 1) as $value) {

    echo $value;
}
```

Resultado:

> 12345678910

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/CzbLsX)

Ainda pensando numa maneira de deixar o código mais simples, poderíamos fazer assim:

```
function xrange($value, $limit, $step = 1)
{
     return new XRange($value, $limit, $step);
}


foreach(xrange(1, 10) as $key => $value) {

}
```

Vale lembrar que entre a implementação de um `Iterator` seria mais rápido do que a função `range`, tendo em vista que, em um processamento de `1` a `10.000`, `range` seria um "vilão" no consumo de memória; já no caso da classe `XRange` teríamos um valor para cada iteração.

Comment: Iterator não seria "mais rápido", na verdade ele provavelmente é mais lento visto que inclui todo overhead da geração e subsequente manipulação do objeto.  O correto é dizer que Iterator seria possívelmente mais eficiente em termos de espaço utlizado (RAM), mas isto apenas se você não for utilizar todos as sequências geradas (ex: se você der um break na iteração quando $value == 5000).

Comment: @BrunoRB eu sempre confundo entre os dois termos. Na verdade, nem sempre o fato de gastar muita memória quer dizer que é mais lento. É a mesma comparação que podemos fazer entre usar `fetch` e `fetchAll`