# Self invoking functions no PHP 7. Quais as vantagens?

Tags: php, php-7

Eu sei que no `javascript` é muito útil a utilização de `self invoking functions`, principalmente quando se trata da proteção do escopo de variáveis.

Eu estava fazendo testes no `PHP 7` e vejo que temos a mesma possibilidade de usar a `Self Invoking Function` - funções que podem ser chamadas ao mesmo tempo que são declaradas.

Exemplo:

```
$gen = (function() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;

    return 3;
})()


foreach ($gen as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

A saída é:

```
1
2
3
```

Nesse caso do uso do [`Generator`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50208/quais-as-vantagens-de-usar-um-generator-yield-no-php), vejo muita utilidade.

Quais são outras possíveis vantagens na utilização do `Self Invoking Function` em `PHP7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O recurso vai na direção do que chamamos, em outras linguagens, de [*delegate functions*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx). Há até [uma proposta para o PHP 7 em que o conceito está até melhor desenvolvido](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generator-delegation).

A vantagem deste tipo de função (que até podemos chamar de função anônima) é a possibilidade de definir a função dinamicamente. Este exemplo que você colocou não é exatamente bom, então vou montar outro. Suponha uma função que realize soma de quadrados:

```
$squares = (function($meu_array) {
    foreach ($meu_array as $elemento) 
    {
        yield $elemento * $elemento;
    }
})()
```

Você pode usar assim:

```
foreach ($squares(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

A saída deve ser:

```
1
4
9
16
25
```

Agora, suponha que você quer a soma dos quadrados até um determinado número, e esse número só é conhecido em tempo de execução:

```
$squares = (function($meu_array, $limite) {
    foreach ($meu_array as $elemento) 
    {
        var $numero = $elemento * $elemento;
        if ($numero <= $limite ) yield $numero;
    }
})()
```

Podemos usar assim:

```
var $limite = 20;
foreach ($squares(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), $limite) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Saída:

```
1
4
9
16
```

Comment: Olha, esse exemplo foi fino, hein.

Comment: Melhorei ele. Agora sim está adequado.

Comment: Pra quem não gosta de PHP, até que está sabendo muita coisa, hein.

Comment: Eu era programador PHP. Acho que já te falei.

Comment: Acho que vai rolar um "mortar" desse jeito