# O que são as private e public keys?

Tags: criptografia, ssl

Depois de apanhar e quebrar a cabeça para instalar certificados ssl no Apache, surgiram algumas dúvidas na minha cabeça a respeito de algumas nomenclaturas que foram aparecendo de acordo com as pesquisas que eu estava fazendo para conseguir ajuda na internet.

O que mais chamou atenção foi quando eu tentava configurar o apontamento das chaves, nos arquivo de configuração do Apache2, onde eu teria que apontar para dois arquivos, sendo eles chave-pública e chave-privada (em inglês denonimados de *public key* e *private key*).

Eu queria entender:

- o que cada uma desses dois tipos de chaves significam?
- Por que elas são usadas em certificados SSL?
- Uma chave-privada tem alguma relação (uma relação de dependência, por exemplo) com a chave-pública?
- Elas seguem algum padrão (pois eu sempre vejo essas chaves com um código parecido com um base64)?
- Quais são as extensões de arquivos padrões para identificar cada uma delas?

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais são os benefícios de se usar HTTPS?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49561/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-benef%C3%ADcios-de-se-usar-https)

Answer (score 6):

Como já fizeram a resposta curta e grossa, vou fazer a longa.

Para entender os termos 'chave pública' e 'chave privada' é preciso saber um pouco sobre algoritmos de encriptação.

### Introdução a Encriptação

Algoritmos de encriptação tem como objetivo garantir que um **emissor** troque uma **mensagem** com um **destinatário** sem que intermediários a obtenham.

Na Internet, eles são responsáveis por impedir estranhos de ler os seus preciosos dados pessoais. Afinal, você não quer pessoas xeretando o seu e-mail ou pior, o número do seu cartão de crédito!

Existem duas formas principais de fazer isso.

**Algoritmos simétricos** usam uma única chave, conhecida antemão por tanto o emissor quanto o destinatário. O workflow é simples: o emissor encripta a mensagem usando a chave e manda o conteúdo criptografado pela internet. O receptor então recebe a mensagem e descriptografa ela usando essa mesma chave.

Como você pode ter percebido, esse tipo de algoritmo tem um problema: é preciso que ambos os lados da conversa saibam qual é a chave para descriptografar a mensagem! Como mandar mensagens seguras para destinatários desconhecidos? Simples.

**Algoritmos assimétricos** trabalham não com uma, mas duas chaves:

- Uma **chave pública**, disponível a todos, é usada para criptografar a mensagem. Essa chave *não consegue descriptografar*.
- Uma **chave privada**, conhecida SOMENTE pelo destinatário, tem o poder de *descriptografar as mensagens.*

Algoritmos assimétricos funcionam (quase) como caixas de correio: Qualquer emissor pode colocar(encriptografar) uma mensagem na sua caixa, mas somente você, o destinatário, pode ler.

### Com relação aos tópicos da pergunta

> o que cada uma desses dois tipos de chaves significam?

Espero que a explicação acima tenha respondido.

> Por que elas são usadas em certificados SSL

Certificados são uma forma de algoritmo assimétrico. Quando você quer mandar algo importante para um site, você primeiro encripta os seus dados usando o certificado público do site. Assim você garante que somente o dono do site pode ler suas informações.

> Uma chave-privada tem alguma relação (uma relação de dependência, por exemplo) com a chave-pública?

Bem, para criptografar algo você precisa da pública e para descriptografar a privada. Não faz muito sentido ter uma sem a outra.

> Elas seguem algum padrão (pois eu sempre vejo essas chaves com um código parecido com um base64)?

Existem vários padrões de certificado. Um exemplo bastante comum é o [X509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509). Todos os padrões que eu conheço para certificados são binários, por questão de performance.

> Quais são as extensões de arquivos padrões para identificar cada uma delas?

Existem várias extensões diferentes para certificados. Se você entende inglês sugiro que de uma olhada [neste](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2010/11/04/various-ssltls-certificate-file-typesextensions/) blog.

### Outras Perguntas

> Tanto a chave privada quanto a chave pública são codificados em X509?

Sim.

Comment: Uma última questão: Tanto a chave privada quanto a chave pública são codificados em X509?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters respondido acima.

Comment: Creio que há certa confusão quanto ao uso dos pares de chaves nos certificados. Um certificado é usado exclusivamente para **assinar** mensagens (a chave privada assina, a chave pública verifica a assinatura), nunca pra cifrar. A cifragem é feita usando um segundo par de chaves, efêmero, criado unicamente para aquela sessão e depois descartado. Para mais detalhes, sugiro a pergunta ["Como o HTTPS (SSL) funciona?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28828/215)

Answer (score 0):

As chave publica e privadas estão relacionados a sua funcionalidade, onde e quando se precisa enviar dados, considera se o cenário cliente server.

Exemplo enviando um formulário(cliente), pegue minha chave publica codifique os dados e me envie seu formulário.
Server, formulário chegando até mim, então pego minha chave que só eu conheço e uso para abrir as informações que recebi do formulário.

Isso é a forma simplificada do processo, elas tem total relação de dependência pois se pegar uma chave outra qualquer, com minha chave privada o server não vai conseguir abrir.

As chaves são base 64Bits, geralmente não tem como saber que é publica e privada a não ser pela própria extensão. pois elas se assemelham justamente para dificultar decodificar as chaves com algumas politicas de quebra de chave.

Isso é que posso contribuir para a questão, existem detalhes mais aprofundados, livros, faculdades e muitas teorias para o assunto.